# I'm trying to run `vagrant provision` on PowerShell Window for Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, windows, provisioning, powershell

Here is what it replies:

`Windows is not officially supported for the Ansible Control Machine.
Please check https://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html#control-machine-requirements`

What should I do? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 viable options to run ansible on windows 10:

- Install a linux vm with your favorite virtualization tool and run ansible inside that vm.
- [Run ansible from WSL](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/using-ansible-through-windows-10s-subsystem-linux)

With the first option, you will need to install vagrant inside the vm + all virtualization tools needed.

With the second option, you will then need to [install vagrant in WSL as well](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/wsl.html) and configure it to access your windows environment.